# Only get items in list that are in another list

Tags: python, list

I have a constant list that looks like this:

```
some_list = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday" "sunday"]
```

I have another list of strings that can take any shape, but let's say it looks like this for example:

```
sentence_list = ["i'm going this friday", "i'm not going", "i plan to go saturday"]
```

What I'd like to have returned is a new list that contains only the strings that are present in `some_list`

```
new_list = ["i'm going this friday", "i plan to go saturday"]
```

I tried doing

```
 any(sentence in sentence_list for sentence in some_list)
```

However, this just tells me that a sentence in the list does contain things in `some_list` How can I get the result I want?

Comment: `any` isn't what you need (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any). Try something along lines of `[sentence in sentence_list if sentence in some_list]`

Answer (score 3):

`[sentence for sentence in sentence_list if any(key in sentence for key in some_list)]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
>>> new_list = [sentence for sentence in sentence_list if any (word in sentence for word in some_list)]
>>> new_list
["i'm going this friday", 'i plan to go saturday']
```

Answer (score 2):

For each string in `sentence_list`, you need to check if any of the words from `some_list` are in there. You already have the code for testing if a single sentence contains one of the strings from `some_list`. Let's express that as a lambda for checking whether a given sentence is valid or not:

```
valid_sentence = lambda sentence: any(word in sentence for word in some_list)
```

Now you just need to do it for every sentence:

```
filter(valid_sentence, sentence_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
some_list = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
sentence_list = ["i'm going this friday", "i'm not going", "i plan to go saturday"]

newlist = []
for i in sentence_list:
    for j in i.split(" "):
        if j in some_list:
            newlist.append(i)
print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
some_list = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]

sentence_list = ["i'm going this friday", "i'm not going", "i plan to go saturday"]

new_list = []

for day in some_list:
    for sentence in sentence_list:
        if day in sentence:
            new_list.append(sentence)

print(new_list)
```

Result:

> ["i'm going this friday", 'i plan to go saturday']

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use a list comprehension solution without the need of function any():

```
[sentence for sentence in sentence_list if [day for day in some_list if day in sentence]]
```